# How to merge two DataTables with same Column.Counts

Tags: c#, .net

I get 2 data tables, the `Column.Count` is the same, but the table header is not the same, I tried `ImportRow` method, but when the row imported to the new `DataTable`, the `ItemArray` turned to `System.DBNull`.

```cs
// dt1 only contains a row ,this row will be the header of newDt
// dt2 contains Data that need to Merge to the newDt

public static DataTable MergeDataTable(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    DataTable newDt = new DataTable();

    newDt = dt1.Copy();

    foreach (var row in dt2.Rows)
    {
        newDt.ImportRow(row);
    }

    return newDt;
}
```

In the Debug window, row object contains all the data of a row in `dt2`, but when imported to `newDt`, it turned to `{}(System.DBNull)...`

Comment: What data does dt2 contain?

Comment: dt1 from a Excel Template,  dt2'data comes from a List, the header of two header is not the same..but they get the same column counts.  So is there any way to write data to newDt forcely?

Comment: Its likely the data in dt2 can't be cast to whatever you have in dt1

Comment: Column.Count. But what about the datatypes?

Comment: [`DataTable.Merge` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge) if the column names and types match

Comment: Likely the data types of the columns are different between dt1 and dt2. Excel ADODB/ODBC drivers tend to sniff the first few rows to discern the data types and assume the entire data set will be of the same time. Read up on the TypeGuessRows parameter at [Initializing the Microsoft Excel driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/initializing-the-microsoft-excel-driver?tabs=office-2016)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
public static DataTable MergeDataTable(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    DataTable newDt = new DataTable();

    List<DataRow> rows = dt1.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList();
    rows.AddRange(dt2.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList());

    foreach (DataRow dataRow in rows)
    {
        newDt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return newDt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DataTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)` instead of `DataTable.ImportRow(row)`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt1 = CreateFirtsTable();
        var dt2 = CreateSecondTable();
        var dt = Merge(dt1, dt2);
    }

    static DataTable CreateFirtsTable()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn("String", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Int", typeof(int))
        });
        dt.Rows.Add("one", 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("two", 2);
        dt.Rows.Add("three", 3);

        return dt;
    }

    static DataTable CreateSecondTable()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn("Int", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("String", typeof(string))
        });
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "four");
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "five");
        dt.Rows.Add(6, "six");

        return dt;
    }

    static DataTable Merge(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
    {
        if (dt1.Columns.Count != dt2.Columns.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException("Columns count does not match");

        var dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (var col in dt1.Columns)
            dt.Columns.Add();

        foreach (var row in dt1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
            dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);

        foreach (var row in dt2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
            dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);

        return dt;
    }
}
```

`dt` is:

```
one   | 1
------|------
two   | 2
------|------
three | 3
------|------
4     | four
------|------
5     | five
------|------
6     | six
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like this:

```
DataTable dt = GetIssues(fmWeb); 
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

public static DataTable CustomMerge(DataSet ds)
{
    DataTable MergedDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataView dv;

    List<string> columnName= new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
    {
        MergedDataTable.Merge(ds.Tables[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MergedDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        columnName.Add(MergedDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    }

    dv = new DataView(MergedDataTable);
    return dv.ToTable(true, columnName.ToArray<string>());
}
```